# Edit a question doesn't reflect the same content

Tags: bug, questions, editing

For this [question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/7929/any-open-souce-system-for-online-ticket-sale), if you click on edit, the textarea will be fill up with a more recent edit (I think).

The displayed question is:

> Hi All: Is there any open source project that can be used to build a on-line ticket sales system, like: ticketmaster or eventbrite etc..? Thanks!

The edit show:

> Is there any open source project that can be used to build a on-line ticket sales system, like: ticketmaster or eventbrite etc..? Thanks!

I don't know if I have to post this here or on the global meta.se.

Comment: That's a weird one. It does look like an edited version appears when you click edit, but there's no edit history. I'll report it in the Moderators chat room. I think the developers watch the bug tag in all meta sites, but if I report it in chat they might see it sooner.

Comment: Here's the answer I got: 
@paulmorriss In theory, yes
Policy is you can post bug reports for the SE network on child metas as well.

Comment: @paulmorriss This is just fine here, and it's not a bug (writing an answer now).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), there's [a filter that automatically removes silly stuff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/162704) like "Hi All" from posts. It doesn't catch *everything*, but it works fairly well.

The question in question however was originally asked on Dec 24 '10, before the filter was implemented, which explains why "Hi All" is still there. When you tried to edit it, the filter run automatically, removing the silly salutation.

Comment: Oh I see. I've heard about this filter but since I do few edits I always see some "Hi there", "Thanks for help", etc ... I was wondering if this filter still works. As you said *it doesn't catch everything*. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @j0k Here's [the regex](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/162704), it's pretty basic really. "Thanks!" survived because it's at the end of the post.